# How to resolve messed up efi without data loss

Tags: boot, dual-boot, data-recovery, grub-efi

was having Ubuntu installed along with MacOS Catalina. I need windows for project work so I decided to create a partition and flash windows in it... Doing this I messed up and there was showing no option to boot into MacOS. Right now I can log in into Ubuntu with no problem so is there any way, by which I can boot into MacOS located at disk0s2? Disk0s1 is EFI I have access to /EFI/EFI from Ubuntu I can see 4 folders there... Apple, Boot, Microsoft, Ubuntu. What should I do? P.s.: I have a blank partition of 50GB and in external hard disk I have a 5.5GB ISO file of old version of MacOS file.

Comment: Try selecting MacOS from the EFI menu (type some function key at power-up to get a selection of boot device/OS). Not sure what the Windows install did if the EFI/Apple folder (and contents) still exists.

Comment: Doesn't show MacOS in Boot menu... Don't know why but it isn't there...

Comment: From Ubuntu try running sudo update-grub to see if that picks up the macos in the grub menu the next time you boot.  I suppose you could try to use efibootmgr to add back the macos boot item if the mac bootloaders are still there (EFI/Apple).

Comment: I found out where things went wrong. I am posting answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is detailed process of what I did to turn ON MacOSX.

**Step-1 : sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda**

```
derek@derek-MacBookPro:~$ sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.3

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.
Disk /dev/sda: 490234752 sectors, 233.8 GiB
Model: APPLE SSD SM0256
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/4096 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): F3A656EC-6327-4E3B-B8D4-24D7C90F18DD
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 490234718
Partitions will be aligned on 8-sector boundaries
Total free space is 105470093 sectors (50.3 GiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1              40          409639   200.0 MiB   EF00  EFI System Partition
   2          409640       294970071   140.5 GiB   FFFF  MacOSX
   3       400439296       490233855   42.8 GiB    8300
```

***Step-2: sudo efibootmgr -v***

```
derek@derek-MacBookPro:~$ sudo efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 5 seconds
BootOrder: 0002,0001,0000,0080
Boot0000* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,ba591477-7a5b-4314-95e2-3ea359d0b28c,0x28,0x64000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0001* Linux HD(1,GPT,ba591477-7a5b-4314-95e2-3ea359d0b28c,0x28,0x64000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\grub.efi)FFFF.0000.0080...............
Boot0002* Linux HD(1,GPT,ba591477-7a5b-4314-95e2-3ea359d0b28c,0x28,0x64000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\grub.efi)4.1.2.3............
Boot0080*   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1c,0x4)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/Sata(0,0,0)/HD(1,GPT,ba591477-7a5b-4314-95e2-3ea359d0b28c,0x28,0x64000)/File(\EFI\BOOT\BOOTX64.efi)
BootFFFF*   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1c,0x4)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/Sata(0,0,0)/HD(1,GPT,ba591477-7a5b-4314-95e2-3ea359d0b28c,0x28,0x64000)/File(\EFI\BOOT\BOOTX64.efi)
```

***Step-3 : sudo sgdisk -i 2 /dev/sda***

```
derek@derek-MacBookPro:~$ sudo sgdisk -i 2 /dev/sda
Partition GUID code: FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF (Unknown)
Partition unique GUID: 4D99D8DA-F7FF-451F-B9F2-074010EBF442
First sector: 409640 (at 200.0 MiB)
Last sector: 294970071 (at 140.7 GiB)
Partition size: 294560432 sectors (140.5 GiB)
Attribute flags: 0000000000000000
Partition name: 'MacOSX'
```

***Step-4: sudo sgdisk -t 2:7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC /dev/sda***

```
derek@derek-MacBookPro:~$ sudo sgdisk -t 2:7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC /dev/sda
[sudo] password for derek: 
Warning: The kernel is still using the old partition table.
The new table will be used at the next reboot or after you
run partprobe(8) or kpartx(8)
The operation has completed successfully.
```

After this, I restarted the MacBook and I was able to see the MacOS in boot Menu as the format was reverted back to **AFPS**